# Descargar código fuente de página web

Tags: html

Quisiera descargar todos los archivos de una página web al inspeccionarla pero no sé cómo hacerlo. He inspeccionado la página y quiero descargar todos los archivos o la carpeta madre que encapsula a todos.

[image: principal]

Comment: Dale `CTRL + S` a la pagina y guardala.

Comment: @Riven no funciona,¿primero donde debo darle click ?

Comment: En cualquier parte de la pagina, de todas maneras ten en cuenta que la solucion basica que te di solamente te descargara archivos no modulares de la pagina.

Comment: Aunque sabes?, veo que desde la pestaña que tienes abierta puedes directamente descargar los archivos, otra forma de hacerlo es que si tienes una consola de linux a la mano puedes hacer algun `wget` con ciertos parametros para descargar archivos de la pagina.

Comment: @Riven pero necesito descargar todo

Comment: wget -m -p -E -k www.example.com

Comment: @Fedex7501 no tengo linux

Comment: hay wget para windows

Comment: Piensa que al descargarlos con wget tan solo obtienes el resultado HTML de lo que se esté procesando alli, más los archivos JS, CSS, etc pero puede ser que algun contenido sea generado dinámicamente con javascript, con lo cual ese contenido no podras descargártelo facilmente pues wget no interpreta el javascript.

Comment: @masterguru es un punto muy importante que debe tener en cuenta la usuaria.